# Update xml tag in a CLOB column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, xmltype, updatexml

I have this xml value in a CLOB column in Oracle 11g:

```
<Energy xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/notifications/2009/01/notification">    
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <FirstName>MAR</FirstName>
    <Name>VAN HALL</Name>
    <Email/><Telephone>000000000</Telephone>
    <InsertDate>2013-10-09</InsertDate>
</Energy>
```

I want to update the value of InserDate for several rows.

I was using next below sql command:

```
update tmp_tab_noemail_test p1 
set p1.sce_msg = updatexml(xmltype(p1.sce_msg),
                 '//Energy/InsertDate/text()','Not Valid').getClobVal()
```

But is not working.

Do you have some ideas to modify only the values of the xml tag of InsertDate?

Thanks in advances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a namespace in your top-level Energy node, so you aren't matching without; [the UPDATEXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions225.htm) shows you can optionally supply a namespace string.

So you can do this, using your example data:

```
create table tmp_tab_noemail_test (sce_msg clob);
insert into tmp_tab_noemail_test values (
'<Energy xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/notifications/2009/01/notification">    
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <FirstName>MAR</FirstName>
    <Name>VAN HALL</Name>
    <Email/><Telephone>000000000</Telephone>
    <InsertDate>2013-10-09</InsertDate>
</Energy>');

update tmp_tab_noemail_test p1 
set p1.sce_msg = updatexml(xmltype(p1.sce_msg),
  '/Energy/InsertDate/text()','Not Valid',
  'xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/notifications/2009/01/notification"').getClobVal();
```

After which you end up with:

```
select sce_msg from tmp_tab_noemail_test;

SCE_MSG                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Energy xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/notifications/2009/01/notification"><Gender>M</Gender><FirstName>MAR</FirstName><Name>VAN HALL</Name><Email/><Telephone>000000000</Telephone><InsertDate>Not Valid</InsertDate></Energy>
```

Or with slightly less scrolling:

```
select XMLQuery('//*:InsertDate' passing XMLType(sce_msg) returning content) as insertdate
from tmp_tab_noemail_test;

INSERTDATE                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<InsertDate xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/notifications/2009/01/notification">Not Valid</InsertDate>
```

---

You could also wildcard the update:

```
update tmp_tab_noemail_test p1 
set p1.sce_msg = updatexml(xmltype(p1.sce_msg),
  '/*:Energy/*:InsertDate/text()','Not Valid').getClobVal();
```

... but it's probably better to specify the namespace.

Comment: @Alex Poole: I have similar requirement, but instead of updating value inside tag, I need to update tag name itself. For example I need to update 'InsertDate' tag to 'insertDate' tag. Any suggestion please? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @SivaramChintalapudi - you should ask a new question giving all the relevant information. (But look at FLWOR `modify rename node` first maybe.)