# ORACLE - Update multiple attribute in xml

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have this situation

```
create table FOO (
BAR clob
);

create table FOO2 (
VALUE_OLD varchar2(255),
VALUE_NEW varchar2(255)
);

insert into FOO2 values (1, 10);
insert into FOO2 values (2, 20);
insert into FOO2 values (3, 30);

insert into FOO (BAR) values (
'<xml>
  <ope cod_ope="123" cod_sogg="1"/>
  <ope cod_ope="456" cod_sogg="2"/>
  <ope cod_ope="789" cod_sogg="3"/>
</xml>'
);
```

And I need to update the attribute cod_sogg in every ope tag with the value_new in the table FOO2 (note that the number of ope tag is unknown, there could be 100 ope tags) so the xml result should be

```
<xml>
  <ope cod_ope="123" cod_sogg="10"/>
  <ope cod_ope="456" cod_sogg="20"/>
  <ope cod_ope="789" cod_sogg="30"/>
</xml>
```

I tryed with something like

```
update FOO set BAR = UPDATEXML(
  xmltype(BAR),
  '/xml/ope/@cod_sogg', 
  (
    select VALUE_NEW from FOO2 where value_old = extractvalue(xmltype(BAR), '/xml/ope/@cod_sogg')
  )
  ).getClobVal();
```

But obviously i get

```
Errore SQL: ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE restituisce il valore di un solo nodo
19025. 00000 -  "EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node"
*Cause:    Given XPath points to more than one node.
*Action:   Rewrite the query so that exactly one node is returned.
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Does this help? [Update xml tag in a CLOB column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002954/update-xml-tag-in-a-clob-column-in-oracle)

Comment: Not really, the problem here is to update multiple attribute with the same xpath

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous block to do so.

```
BEGIN
FOR I IN (SELECT VALUE_OLD, VALUE_NEW FROM FOO2)
LOOP
UPDATE FOO
SET BAR=to_clob(updatexml( xmltype.createxml(BAR),
                          '/xml/ope[@cod_sogg="' || I.VALUE_OLD || '"]/@cod_sogg',I.VALUE_NEW));
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03e5d92d7c18c149a36e60c59264c48c)

Comment: this works, thanks, but I'd rather not to cycle the FOO2 table, I'll have thousands of record in that table